# Trigger Typo3 realurl extension to generate url via PHP code

Tags: php, typo3, realurl

Knows someone a way to trigger realurl Typo3 extension to trigger the generation of urls? Some like

Pseudo code: realurl->generateUrl($page_uid);

We use the extension in a setup and it works great in the frontend, but because we access some page via restler extension, we need the urls directly in the tx_realurl_pathdata.

We tried the way to typolink_URL but for some reason the realurl didn't worked here.

Answer (score 1):

In the frontend context you can simply use `ContentObjectRenderer::typoLink_URL()` which will automatically invoke RealURL to build a human readable URL.

In the backend context you'll have to instantiate quite a few dummy objects to get closer to frontend URLs. Most of the time you'll run `typoLink_URL()` and fix errors one by one. You can also have a look at what TYPO3 does to [handle regular frontend requests](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/ea7f8c63f554465a7de64297d6a7592850b3abda/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Http/RequestHandler.php#L81). Various extensions for redirects already do something like this, e.g. [my_redirects](https://github.com/koninklijke-collective/my_redirects/blob/6d8260a/Classes/Service/RedirectService.php#L288).

An easier solution to all of this would be the [pagepath](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/pagepath/) extension which defers URL generation. Of course, you won't get nice URLs immediately, only after a redirect.